# In Spring Boot project I want to make one to many relationship but I am confused about rest output

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I created one project using spring boot, spring data JPA. In that project I use Employee and Department entity in that `ManyToOne` bi-direction relationship at the time I run the project it is an unexpected result
Employee.java

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Employee {
  @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;
        private String firstname;
        private String lastname;
        private Long mobile;
        private String email;
        @ManyToOne
        private Department department;

    public Employee(Long id, String firstname, Department department) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.department = department;
    }}
```

Department.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Department {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
private String Departmentname;
private String Address;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "department",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Employee>employees= new ArrayList<>();

    public Department(String departmentname, String address) {
        Departmentname = departmentname;
        Address = address;
    }

    public void addEmployees(Employee employee)
    {
        this.employees.add(employee);
    }
    public void removeEmployees(Employee employee)
    {
        this.employees.remove(employee);
    }
}
```

EmployeeRepository.java(I)

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepositroy extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT e FROM Employee e join e.department WHERE e.firstname =:n")
    public List<Employee> getName(@Param("n") String firstname);

    @Query("SELECT e FROM Employee e")
    public List<Employee> getData();
}
```

EmployeeController.java

```
@RestController
public class EmployeeController {
    @Autowired
EmployeeRepositroy employeeRepositroy;
@GetMapping("/record/{name}")
    public Object GetNameByRecords(@PathVariable("name") String firstname)
{
return employeeRepositroy.getName(firstname);
}

}
```

Error is here https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fD5eChDowY7F8tAE4ORM_V7ulSt6vHe23SKmkx22M18/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: please add some details about unexpected result, your expectations and logs if there's any error

Comment: Your error log isn't sufficient to trace the cause of failure. Please provide more details about the error

Comment: provide logs in document file

Comment: access denied to error on google docs

Comment: restrictions removed on log file

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite recursion when trying to return the object. When Jackson tries to serialize your return object, it will get stuck on the circular reference between Employee and Department. you will need to mark one of them with @JsonIgnore. Either the Employees list in Department or the Department field in Employee.

Comment: Also on a side note. There are a few things that I would clean up. First you have the dependency injected into the controller using field injection and have it set to the default access. You should limit the access to that variable as much as possible and use constructor injection so it will be easier to test using mocks since you won't reflection or Spring tools to run your tests but can build the objects normally. Also you should avoid returning Object from your endpoint since it does no type checking and makes it hard for people reading it to tell what should be expected to be returned.